# Android - Error referencing another class

Tags: android, unhandled-exception

I'm basically giving this a good shot at creating a class where I can pass in all of my parameters for a stored procedure execution of to return a dataset.

Here is my call

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        List<String> myargs = new ArrayList<String>();
        myargs.add("_caseId|apples");

        WebServicesController.SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure("DJProvider_Delete", myargs);


        return null;
    }
```

I'm getting the error at `WebServicesController.SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure`.  The error is unhandled exceptions XMLPullParser,JavaIOException.

This is the class i'm calling

```
    public static void SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure(String METHOD_NAME,List<String> ArgumentPipeValue) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    //make new soap Object
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    //add arguments in to
    for (String arg : ArgumentPipeValue) {
        String[] splitArgs = arg.split("|");
        Request.addProperty(splitArgs[0], splitArgs[1]);
    }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(NAMESPACE+ASMXURL);



    transport.call(NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME,soapEnvelope);
    resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

}
```

This really is my first web service application for android.  I'm fairly positive that I get the error because my void has `throws XmlPullParserException, IOException`.  But i do not know how to add that syntax to my call.

Also I don't understand why if I remove that, `transport.call(NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME,soapEnvelope);` then produces the same error `unhandled exception`

Any help is grealy appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        List<String> myargs = new ArrayList<String>();
        myargs.add("_caseId|apples");

        try{
             WebServicesController.SoapActionExecuteStoredProcedure("DJProvider_Delete", myargs);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

    return null;
}
```